# How can i restore $PATH to default on nixos

Tags: linux, nixos

I accidentally unset all the directories of $PATH while trying to add a new one but i do something wrong and now theres nothing programs work.
I'm also trying `set PATH /usr/.nix-profile/bin`

Answer (score 1):

```
export PATH=/run/current-system/sw/bin
```

should be enough to restore your path to something useful. You also can exit the terminal and start a new one